# Library tab in scenebuilder disappeared

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Clicked something and cant see the library tab anymore. Here is a picture of my scenebuilder:
[image]

As you can tell, library tab is missing. I've tried deleting and recreating the FXML to no avail.

Comment: What about `View -> Show Library`?

Comment: It worked! Go ahead and make it an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scene Builder allows you showing and hiding both lateral panels at your convenience.

The `View` menu gives you access to:

- Hide/Show Left Panel
- Hide/Show Right Panel

[image: Hide panels]

And also for the Left Panel you can:

- Hide/Show Library
- Hide/Show Document

In case you accidentally hid the library panel you can enable it easily with `View -> Show Library`:

[image: Show library]

Note that the layout of Scene Builder for a given FXML file is persisted in the user preferences for this given file, so after you save and exit, when coming back to the file you will get the exact same layout as the previous Scene Builder session.